# Copying files from multiple directories

Tags: files, file-copy

I want to copy a single file from 10 different directories and append them in another directory.

Comment: Show an example of what you want to do..

Comment: what do you mean by 'paste'?  append them all, one after to the other, to a single file?

Comment: how can it be done with single command line. i need to do it for like 100 directories after that.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do that.  One of the simplest is:

```
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5 dir6 dir7 dir8 dir9 dir10 ; do
    cat "$d/filename" >> /path/to/other/dir/filename
done
```

or, slightly better:

```
#! /bin/bash

outdir='/path/to/otherdir'
filename='filename.txt'

sourcedirs="dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5 dir6 dir7 dir7 dir9 dir10"

for d in $sourcedirs ; do
    cat "$d/$filename" >> "$outdir/$filename"
done
```

The advantage with this version is that just by changing the `$sourcedirs` variable, you can make it work with any number of directories.  Also, `$sourcedirs` doesn't have to be manually enumerated, it can be generated by another command (e.g. `find /top/level/directory -type d`).

e.g. this version lets you specify the top-level directory as the first (and only) argument on the command-line.  It then generates `$sourcedirs` as a list of all 1st-level subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`) of that top-level directory.

```
#! /bin/bash

topdir="$1"    

outdir='/path/to/otherdir'
filename='filename.txt'

find "$topdir" -maxdepth 1 -exec cat "{}/$filename" \; >> "$outdir/$filename"
```

If you want to concatenate a list of all files matching a certain filename in a directory tree, no matter how deep in the tree they are, you'd do something more like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

topdir="$1"

outdir='/path/to/otherdir'
filename='filename.txt'

find "$topdir" -type f -name "$filename" -exec cat {} + >> "$outdir/$filename"
```

or as a one-liner:

```
find /top/dir -type f -name 'filename.txt' -exec cat {} + \
    >> /path/to/other/dir/filename.txt
```

Comment: i need something so that everytime i dont have to define the directories.  i just need to define the directory and all the subdirectories containing the file should be read.

Comment: @PRATEEKBHATT The `find` one-liner mentioned would be the shortest and most versatile approach.

Comment: The `find` versions only work if all of the files to be copied are in the same directory tree(s) (and you want to copy ALL found instances of the file).  The `for` loop versions are better if the directories are scattered all over the filesystem or if you don't want to copy every instance found in a directory tree (or directory trees).